# Increment a variable already incremented in another loop

Tags: batch-file, variables, while-loop, increment

I would like to automate the execution of several commands to retrieve files from pods, with oc client.

I succeeded in incrementing the name of my variables, but I can't increment them in another loop to get their content.

```
@echo off
set /p "nbPod=How many times should RSYNC be used?? "

set num=0

for /l %%p in (1, 1, %nbPod%) do (
    set /a "num = num + 1"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set /p "podName!num!= Enter pod name for pod number %%p ? "
)

set /a iteration=1

:loop
if %iteration% leq %num% (
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo %podName!iteration!%
    ::oc rsync %podName!iteration!%:/my_command_0
    ::oc rsync %podName!iteration!%:/my_command_1 [etc]
    set /a "iteration = iteration + 1"
    goto :loop
)
```

NB : I don't know why but `set /a num+=1` wasn't working.

Comment: The expression `%podName!iteration!%` should read `!podName%iteration%!`, because the index `%iteration%` must become expanded first…

Comment: @aschipfl It does work... As this is a comment I can't put your answer in solution.
This is the first time I've done batch, I didn't mind trying this combination. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look at this: [Arrays, linked lists and other data structures in cmd.exe (batch) script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10167990)…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
:: remove variables starting podname
FOR  /F "delims==" %%b In ('set podname 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%b="
set /p "nbPod=How many times should RSYNC be used?? "

for /l %%p in (1, 1, %nbPod%) do set /p "podName%%p= Enter pod name for pod number %%p ? "

for /l %%p in (1, 1, %nbPod%) do (
   echo !podName%%p!
   rem within a block, use REM, not :: as :: is a broken label which terminates the block
   rem oc rsync !podName%%p!:/my_command_0
   rem oc rsync !podName%%p!:/my_command_1 [etc]
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.

A few little issues with your code.

`setlocal` makes a copy of the current environment and processing continues using that new environment. An `endlocal` statement disposes of the new environment and restores the original. Reaching physical end-of-file is an implicit `endlocal`.

Consequently, it's normal to follow the initial `@echo off` with a `setlocal` as any statements executed before the `setlocal` are retained in the environment after the batch ends, which can cause confusion for subsequent batches as the variables use may be unexpectedly set.

There is a limit to the number of nested open `setlocal`s that can be used (about 300). Unlikely to be a problem in this case, but something to note.

`nbpod` is your limit, so there's no requirement to use `num` or `iteration`.

I've no idea what the comments in the final loop are, but they **MUST** be `rem` statements within a block (parenthesised sequence of commands). OK- probably they are commented-out `what I'm actually doing` lines....

The `for /f ... %%b` command will process the list generated by `set` command, which would be something like

```
podname1=one
podname2=two
```

The `delims=` option causes `for/f` to assign the (default) first "token" in the line (`podname1`,`podname2`) to `%%b` and "sets" the value to *nothing*, deleting any stray variables from the environment. The `2^>nul` suppresses error messages if there are no current variables named `podname...`.

Then input the names as `podname1...` according to `%%p`.

And read them back using delayedexpansion, the current value of [podname strung with `%%p`]

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer. 
It's the first time I'm doing batch and I must say that it makes me feel very strange compared to bash. As I don't really understand how to do what I want with this language, I look for the info quite badly, I confess.
For the record, the comments in the last loop were just there to say that this is where I'm going to use !podName%%p! in my command